# Polynom equation and derivative

Tags: polynomials, derivatives

So I have an example explaining derivatives in my textbook but I cannot really understand it, it goes like this:

Solve $f'(x)=0$ if $f(x)= 3x^2 -12x + 10 $

$
f(x) = 3x^2-12x+10\\
f'(x)=3*2x-12 = 6x -12\\
f'(x) = 0 gives 6x-12 = 0\\
x = 2\\
f'(x) = 0 when x=2 
$

What I don't really understand is where the constant "10" went between the first and second step? This is probably something that I've missed while reading the rules for derivatives, but after some searching I still haven't been able to understand it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the derivative of a constant is 0

Comment: Differentiation of a constant wrt. a variable is $0$ That is the reason it doesn't appear after differentiation.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple I missed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of a constant (for example, $10$) is $0$.

In general, the derivative of a polynomial
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$ is
$$f'(x)=na_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+2a^2x+a_1$$
Note that $a_0$ "disappeard". This is because $a_0$ is a constant, so its derivative is zero.

Here, you have $n=2$, $a_0=10, a_1=-12$ and $a_2=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for another way of looking at it...

You know that if $f(x)=x^2$ then $f'(x)=2x$, right ?

In general we have that if $f(x) = x^n$ then $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$.

But for a constant $c = cx^0$, because $x^0 = 1$.

Putting together all of this we get:

$$f(x) = x^2+10 = x^2 + 10x^0$$
so:
$$f'(x) = 2\times x^{2-1} + 0\times 10 \times x^{0-1}$$
$$f'(x) = 2x + 0$$
$$f'(x) = 2x$$